# Filtrando response axios antes de renderizar, com valor retornado de uma api como parâmetro de filtro

Tags: javascript, react, api, axios

Tenho um formulário, que tem dois campo relacionados, um grupo e um subgrupo, logo, quando vou carregar os dados da api para popular a tela, eu recebo todos os grupos e todos os subgrupos, armazeno em um state e passo para o DOM renderizar, existe alguma maneira de utilizar uma informação que recebi dos dados carregados, no caso o grupo(um grupo_id) para filtrar a segunda response antes de carregar a tela? pois quando tento, a o DOM vê os filtrados como undefined

Segue o código exemplo

```
  const [grupo, setGrupo] = useState([]);
  const [subGrupo, setSubGrupo] = useState([]);
  const [subGrupoFilter, setSubgrupoFilter] = useState([]);
  const [metaPessoa,setMetaPessoa] = useState();
    

  async function groupHandler() {
    await api
      .get("/pessoasgrupos", { headers: { token: isAuth().token_lg } })
      .then((response) => {
        setGrupo(response.data);
      });
  }
  async function subgroupHandler() {
    await api
      .get("/pessoassubgrupos", {
        headers: { token: isAuth().token_lg },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setSubGrupo(response.data);
        setSubgrupoFilter(
          response.data.map((sg) => sg.cod_grupoowner === metaPessoa.cod_grupo)
        );
      });
  }

useEffect(() => {
    if (!metaPessoa) {
      if (pessoa) {
        api
          .get("/pessoa", {
            params: { codigo: pessoa, somenteclientes: false },
            headers: { token: isAuth().token_lg },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.statusText == "OK") {
              setMetaPessoa(response.data);
            } else {
              alert("Error");
            }
          });
      }
      groupHandler() 
      subgroupHandler()
    }
  }, []);
```

Quando filtro, e tento renderizar no DOM o resultado, apresenta apenas undefined, apesar que se eu altero algo no código e salvo, o reload do react ativa, e ele deixa de ser undefined e recebe os valores.
Qual seria a melhor maneira de trabalhar esse filtro?

Comment: Não tem como testar seu código, mas você tentou passar `metaPessoa` para o listener do `useEffect`? Não sei se entra em loop infinito, mas estou pensando em como entender o problema.

Comment: Seria interessante,mas o metaPessoa aí no contexto é o datasource do formulário principal da página